# Programatically remove all Bluetooth Devices in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm making a program that has an option for an audio sink via Bluetooth.  I have everything setup to auto accept connections without a pin, music streams, etc.  When I turn the audio sink off, I want to remove all Bluetooth devices.

I found someone that had written a stand alone program that would do what I'm looking for.  His program was:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for device in $(bt-device -l | grep -o "[[:xdigit:]:]\{11,17\}"); do
    echo "removing bluetooth device: $device | $(bt-device -r $device)"
done
```

This does exactly what I want, but I want to be able to do it from within my Python program.  I've read about not using shell=True so found how I was supposed to break it up into 2 processes.

At a command prompt I typed

```
 bt-device -l | grep -o "[[:xdigit:]:]\{11,17\}"
```

and got the following output:

```
C4:91:0C:3A:A8:10
F8:E9:4E:7F:4C:05
```

My current program is:

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['bt-device', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.check_output(['grep', '-o', '"[[:xdigit:]:]\{11,17\}"'], stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err = proc2.communicate()
print('out: {0}'.format(out))
```

My hope would be this produced a list of MAC addresses that I could then use a for loop and use something like this:

```
subprocess.call(('bt-device', '-r', device))
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post.py", line 5, in <module>
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 215, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.
```

If I use Popen for both processes, per the example linked in the comment, I get code that looks like:

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['bt-device', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-o', '"[[:xdigit:]:]\{11,17\}"'], stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err = proc2.communicate()
print('out: {0}'.format(out))
```

When I run it, I get:

```
out:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the docs for `subprocess` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

`call` waits for process to finish and then returns the status code.
You should probably use `Popen` (allows for actual parallel execution like pipes do) or `run` (will wait for command to finish before continuing). See the docs for examples how to do that.